# Uninitialized variables in Android 2d Gallery source code

Tags: android, 2d, gallery, android-source

I was browsing android source code and stumbled here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/master/src/com/android/camera/CropImage.java

the CropImage.java file seem to have some uninitialized variables at lines 740 , 741 etc. I am talking about the mLeft , mRight , mTop and mBottom variables.

They do not seem to be declared anywhere in the class.

Am i missing something here? How does the code compiles with these errors?

Comment: Couldn't find it either just looking through the code. Have you tried just downloading th project and looking at the whole thing in eclipse? My best guess is that its a global variable.(Why would someone do that IDK...lol) But I'd say download the whole thing and compile it (if you haven't already.) and just do a search for it and tell me any additional info.

Comment: good suggestion let me try compiling this thing

Comment: +2 NP. This helps me too. Gettin all touchy feely with the source is fun. So whats the verdict?

Comment: No , it does not complie with android sdk , it uses many internal hidden api calls

like Bitmap.inNativeAlloc etc.
so the problem is not just the uninitialized variables

Answer (score 1):

They are protected members of the parent class (View).

Answer (score 1):

They're initialized in a parent class.

Comment: Which parent? Cause I'm not seeing it in ImageViewTouchBase, nor am I seeing it in ImageView or View? I'm new to the Android scene myself so if its a noobish mistake please provide a link or something. I do see getLeft() and getRight() but not seeing where mLeft and mRight are declared.

Comment: Exactly !! . i don't see them declared anywhere too. can anyone guide us as to exactly where they are (just out of curiosity)

Comment: It is initialized in the setFrame() method in android.view.View, which according to the docs is called during layout. It could simply be that there is never an instance where setFrame() isn't called. Not looking at this in an IDE it's hard to trace all the references in plain text.

Comment: You mean this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html. I still cant seem to find it.

Comment: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/View.java;h=30aebc9fce75cd66f5db0d98c3e78a8a1d0ec93d;hb=HEAD#l7071

Comment: None of this matters anyway. Primitive ints automatically get a value of 0.